# How to create a co-occurence matrix of words with txt in R

Tags: r, matrix, cosine-similarity

I have an unstructured text file with the topic of "anger". What I want to do is to create a co-occurence matrix/vector with "anger" as the column and all the other words in the text as rows. Something like the picture below. So I can further compute the cosine similarities between two words.
I am new with R programming and your reply will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example along with what your expected output should look like.

Comment: Also you are referring to a picture, but your post doesn't contain one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because TO doesn't seem to be active/interested anymore.